# Storing a JWT token

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jwt

I am using JWT for authentication. Now i want to store this token which is being generated in one class, so that any other class can use it until the session expires. What is the best way to do it. My application is in spring boot.
Adding more. I am making a client which hits a rest webservice with the credentials to get the token. Now i need to store this token somewhere so that further rest requests can use it.
Is it fine to store the token in httpSession and retrieve it further.

Comment: You should never store the JWT token

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.1.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html#getPrincipal()

Comment: @MehrajMalik Sounds like this is on the client, which most certainly does need to store the token.

Comment: @MehrajMalik are you completely sure what are you saying cuz I've seen some cases where it is more than convenient to do so...

Comment: Hi adding more to my question. I am making a client which hits a rest webservice with the credentials to get the token. Now i need to store this token somewhere so that further rest requests can use it.

Comment: This is actually quite a frequently asked question by the people who are new to concept of token based authentication. Usually, the fact that you **DON'T** store JWT is either overlooked or not emphasized by authors of articles. You can read official docs for JWT to gain better understanding how it works: https://jwt.io/introduction

Answer (score 0):

Usually is not a good idea to store a JWT token, since it should contain all the information to identify and authorize a service user without hit the DB/persistence layer.

But maybe there are situations that require to persist it among user data. In this case you can store it in a table/collection and retrieve it while authenticating the user.

If you are using Spring + Spring Security, you can then populate a `token` field in a custom [`User`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.x/api/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.html) implementation.

You can retrieve user data this way:

```
CustomUser userDetails = (CustomUser)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not preferred to store a JWT token in order to protect it from CSRF.

But if you want to persist or use it anyways, one way in spring boot is you can just include the **@RequestHeader** parameter in  any rest request with the value as *"Authorization"* and then you can just fetch out the jwt token from it and can use it as per your functionality :

```
@GetMapping("/abc")
public ResponseEntity<String> getToken(
    @RequestHeader(value="Authorization")  String authorizationHeader){
    String jwt = authorizationHeader.substring(7);
    //your functionality
    return ResponseEntity.ok("JWT Token successfully retrieved");
}
```

Comment: The `substring(7)` is used to get rid of the `"Bearer "` string I assume? Is it guaranteed that it is always 7 characters long? Otherwise splitting by whitespace might be preferable.

Comment: yes correct, it is used to get rid of the "Bearer " string. Yeah it is assumed that the jwt is appended with the "Bearer" and a whitespace.